# How to search if a string is in a very large file in Python

Tags: python, file, search

I have a text file of 100GB containing 100 billion digits of pi, and I need a fast way to search if a 21 digit number is anywhere in this file. Note that the whole file is a single line so no linebreak. I have this function that uses a large buffer (500mb) to load parts of the file and check if the number is there:

```py
def fnd(s):
    start = 2
    with open("pi_dec_1t_01.txt", 'r') as f:
        fsize = os.path.getsize("pi_dec_1t_01.txt")
        bsize = 536870912
        buffer = None
        if start > 0:
            f.seek(start)
        overlap = len(s) - 1
        while True:
            if (f.tell() >= overlap and f.tell() < fsize):
                f.seek(f.tell() - overlap)
            buffer = f.read(bsize)
            if buffer:
                pos = buffer.find(s)
                if pos >= 0:
                    return f.tell() - (len(buffer) - pos)
            else:
                return -1
```

It is fast if I wanted to search only one of these numbers, but I need to search up to 2 billion (until I find one), which would literally take centuries. Any time efficient way to do this? Even if I needed to use some other language or platform

Comment: Why do you need to perform this search?

Comment: It's a challenge to find palindromic prime numbers in the expansion of pi, I already have a code that can generate all palindromic prime numbers of 21 digits fairly fast so searching if they are on pi would be the last step

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to read the file by overlapping chunks and detect the palindromes with a rolling function? You don't need a list of palindromes to be able to recognize one.

Comment: takes roughly 1.6 hours / billion characters, and my estimate is that I will find 1 in 40 billion of these numbers

Answer (score 0):

You could examine this package and maybe find more info on the algorithm it implements: https://pyahocorasick.readthedocs.io/en/latest/